# Pyspark Dictionary GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, unit-testing, pyspark

In pyspark I have a dictionary with only 3 entries, but the value is very long as it is a built up string:

```
{
'Column1':"very long case statement string1",
'Column2':"very long case statement string2",
'Column3':"very long case statement string3"
}
```

With this dictionary I would then use it to build selectExpr in order to create new columns:

```
df.selectExpr('*', *[f"{Condition} as {TargetColumn}" for TargetColumn, Condition in dictionary.items()])
```

This works fine when the value in the dictionary isn't too long, but when it is I get the following error when performing unit test `dataframe1.exceptAll(dataframe2).count()`:

```
[undefined]py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1179.count.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I'm thinking of turning the dictionary into a dataframe instead would that help solve the problem?  and if so how would I do that because dataframe doesn't items so I'd need to change the selectExpr above

Comment: Is it possible that the error comes not from the statement itself, but from the amount or size of the results?

Comment: that's exactly what's happening because currently when I run the `selectExpr` in debug mode it works fine, it only errors when I get to the unit test stage and doing `exceptAll`